# First qpython jnius example not working?

Tags: qpython, pyjnius

I am trying to test pyjnius in the qpython console on Android.

My first line:

```
from jnius import autoclass
```

fails in console with SystemError:  NULL result without error in PyObject_Call

Any suggestions or am I missing something?

(I tested this on two devices with a fresh qpython install.)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you found a solution, but I had a similar experience with QPython and Plyer the otherday. Seems you can not (yet) use Plyer or Pyjnius in the console with QPython. Running the script as a Kivy app makes imports of Plyer or Pyjnius work. Try adding the following lines:

```
    #-*-coding:utf8;-*-
    #qpy:2
    #qpy:kivy
```

on top of your script